# AWS SDK v3 - How to get stack.Tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, sdk, aws-cloudformation

I'm using the AWS JavaScript SDK v3 [CloudFormation client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cloudformation/) to get a list of stacks.

Now I want to get any tags associated with each stack. But I see no way to do it!

Tried looking through docs... expecting something like what they have for aws-sdk/client-mgn

```
import { MgnClient, ListTagsForResourceCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-mgn"; // ES Modules import
// const { MgnClient, ListTagsForResourceCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-mgn"); // CommonJS import
const client = new MgnClient(config);
const input = { // ListTagsForResourceRequest
  resourceArn: "STRING_VALUE", // required
};
const command = new ListTagsForResourceCommand(input);
const response = await client.send(command);
// { // ListTagsForResourceResponse
//   tags: { // TagsMap
//     "<keys>": "STRING_VALUE",
//   },
// };
```

Comment: Did you try using [DescribeStacksCommand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cloudformation/classes/describestackscommand.html)?

Comment: Yes I did... but DescribeStackResourceCommandOutput does not contain Tags

Comment: Sending DescribeStacksCommand results in a DescribeStacksOutput response which contains an array of [Stack](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cloudformation/modules/stack.html), each of which contains array of [Tag](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cloudformation/modules/stack.html#tags), if I'm reading the docs correctly.

Comment: Thanks @jarmod DescribeStacksCommand was the way to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send a [DescribeStacksCommand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cloudformation/classes/describestackscommand.html) for the given stack.

The DescribeStacksOutput response contains an [array of Stack](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cloudformation/modules/stack.html) objects, each of which contains an [array of Tag](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cloudformation/modules/stack.html#tags) objects. For example:

```
const command = new DescribeStacksCommand(input);

const response = await client.send(command);
```

The DescribeStacksOutput response object will look like this:

```
{
  Stacks: [
    {
      StackId: "STRING_VALUE",
      StackName: "STRING_VALUE",
      Description: "STRING_VALUE",
      ...
      Tags: [
        {
          Key: "STRING_VALUE",
          Value: "STRING_VALUE",
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
  NextToken: "STRING_VALUE",
};
```